# Theorem 2.3.8 from Scharlau's book "Quadratic and Hermitian Forms".

Tags: linear-algebra, notation, proof-explanation, bilinear-form

[image]

This is [Theorem 2.3.8](https://books.google.com/books?id=c27pCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA39) from Scharlau's book *Quadratic and Hermitian Forms*
So basically I know that since  $\mathbb{F}_q$/$\mathbb{F}_q^2$  has index 2; it represent 2 classes. One class represents elements which are sqaures and other class represent non-squares.Only problem seems to me in this proof is second line which says that every element of $\mathbb{F}_q$ is sum of two squares implies $\langle 1,1\rangle$ represents $\epsilon$? What is meaning of this notation?

Comment: since $\langle 1,1\rangle$ represents $1^2+1^2$, I think as every element in $\mathbb{F}_q$ is represented by a sum of two squares, therefore $\epsilon$, which represents the class of sum of two squares, can be represented by $\langle 1,1\rangle$

Comment: also see [here](https://www.math.ubc.ca/~cass/research/pdf/FiniteFields.pdf)