# About quadratic forms

Tags: linear-algebra, field-theory, finite-fields

I know that every element is finite field of odd order can be written as sum of two squares. Also I know that since  $\mathbb{F}_q$/$\mathbb{F}_q^2$  has index 2; it represent 2 classes. One class represents elements which are sqaures and other class represent non-squares.

So take $\epsilon$ which can be represent as $\langle 1,1\rangle$
meaning is $\epsilon = x^2+y^2$ then how to show that $\langle 1,1\rangle$ is isometric to  $\langle \epsilon,\epsilon\rangle$?

Basically I want to show  $\langle 1,1\rangle$ is isometric to  $\langle x^2+y^2,x^2+y^2 \rangle$? How to show this in finite field?

Comment: @MorganRodgers https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2900645/theorem-2-3-8-from-scharlaus-book-quadratic-and-hermitian-forms;

Comment: @MorganRodgers Can you please refer to  book which have source in image because notations are bit confusing for me too.

Comment: @MorganRodgers This are the diagonalization of bilinear forms.

Comment: @MorganRodgers We want to prove that <1,1> is isometric to $\langle \epsilon,\epsilon\rangle$? and since $\epsilon$ has representation as sum of two squares; we want to prove $\langle x^2+y^2,x^2+y^2 \rangle$? is isometric to <1,1>. $\langle \epsilon,\epsilon\rangle$ have same diagonal matrix form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to read the earlier chapters and understand the terminology properly.  I don't have a copy of the book, but here are some things.

1. By saying that $1,\epsilon$ are the elements of $\mathbb{F}_{q}^{*}/\mathbb{F}_{q}^{*2}$, this is saying that $\epsilon$ is an arbitrary nonsquare.
2. I am going to guess that when Scharlau says the quadratic form $\langle 1,1 \rangle = x^{2}+y^{2}$ *represents* $\epsilon$, this is defined to mean that there is some vector $v \in \mathbb{F}^{2}$ for which the quadratic form evaluated at $v$ is equal to $\epsilon$. It *does not* mean that $\langle 1,1 \rangle = \epsilon$.
3. As a continuation of 2., the quadratic form $\langle \epsilon, \epsilon \rangle$ would then be $\epsilon x^{2} + \epsilon y^{2}$.

Based on this, you want to show that the quadratic forms given by
$$\langle 1,1 \rangle = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0&1 \end{bmatrix}, \langle \epsilon, \epsilon \rangle = \begin{bmatrix} \epsilon & 0 \\ 0 & \epsilon \end{bmatrix}$$
are isometric, where $\epsilon$ is an arbitrary nonsquare.

To see that these two matrices give equivalent forms, you want to take $a,b$ such that $a^{2}+b^{2} = \epsilon$. Then if you consider
$$ \begin{bmatrix} a & b\\ -b & a \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0\\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} a & -b\\ b& a \end{bmatrix}$$
you should be able to see your result.

Comment: That matrix part is clear but how do we get transition matrix S   to show <1,1> and <epsilon,epsilon> is congruent matrix to show they are isometric since root of epsilon may not lie in field?

Comment: it is necessary condition for matrix to be isometric not sufficient condition; just they wrote in book of section 3.17 in 1 st chapter.